# How to show specific condition in column?

Tags: sql-server

I have this very weird need, I have a query that contains some conditions. Here is a sample one.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, ConditionalColumn FROM Employee
WHERE LastName != 'Ciaz'
```

I want to show the `WHERE` conditional column value in `ConditionalColumn`.
So that column will have `Ciaz` in it.

Comment: But you know the condition, so you can just write `'Ciaz' AS ConditionalColumn`. If this is part of a dynamic SQL scheme where you don't always know the condition, you'll have to put the `WHERE` in as an (escaped!) string. There is no feature in T-SQL where you can copy part of the query parse tree into a column somehow, though getting the execution plan with `SHOWPLAN` is a *bit* like that.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is dynamic actually otherwise it would have been very simple

Comment: If it's dynamic it's still simple, as long as you control the mechanism. Whereas, if you *don't* control the mechanism, it's basically damn near impossible -- you can't do it on the SQL side, at least, not as part of the query execution itself. How is the `WHERE` constructed? More to the point, why do you need this? For debugging purposes, SQL Profiler or whatever mechanism your query building mechanism has for dumping its queries would be more appropriate.

Comment: Where clause is being passed into a variable coming from front end whatever condition user selects, so he can basically select multiple conditions as well like firstname =  this and last name = that but I only want to show last name value i.e that

Comment: Then you're looking at parsing the `WHERE` clause after it's been generated, which is quite different from your original problem. There's two ways: parse the whole query with a T-SQL parser (like the `TSqlParser` class) or accept that this is a bad way to do business, and change the front-end so it passes its search conditions individually, to be translated to a query by the back-end. That's why there is a back-end, after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Param Varchar(MAX) = 'Ciaz'
SELECT FirstName, LastName, @Param AS ConditionalColumn FROM Employee
WHERE LastName != @Param
```

Line 1:  Declare a Varchar (string) variable @Param and assign value of 'Ciaz'.
Line 2:  In Select query with FirstName, LastName add @Param with 'As' keywords and column name 'ConditionalColumn', with this @Param shown as a column in your query.