# How to get specific letters from string in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have this string in the query something like this

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, 'Long Live Pakistan' AS Phrase
FROM EmployeeInfo
```

Is there any way I could get only `live` out of that phrase ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get only 'live' word? `CASE WHEN Phrase LIKE '%Live%' THEN 'Live' END`?

Comment: With `PATINDEX`/`SUBSTRING` on the SQL side, or a regex on the client side. But it won't be a reliable approach if the "phrase" can actually contain [an arbitrary `WHERE` condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52364619/4137916), since T-SQL isn't a regular language.

Answer (score 0):

If you have similar pattern of other string as well then you can do :

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, PARSENAME(REPLACE('Long Live Pakistan', ' ', '.'), 2) AS Phrase
FROM EmployeeInfo einfo;
```

Comment: Fails when I add some other words into the phrase.
Like I added `Australia` and now it returns `Pakistan`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this will check for the word and select the value you were checking for otherwise it will select null:

```
DECLARE @word varchar(20) = 'Live'

SELECT 
  FirstName, LastName, 
  CASE WHEN 'Long Live Pakistan' like '%'+@word+'%' THEN @word END AS Phrase
FROM EmployeeInfo
```

Comment: The phrase is dynamic

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo not sure what you are trying to achieve. Make sure your question is has a clear requirement, and you include test data and expected results. Is the phrase actually a column ?